# bash sort for resolution

Tags: bash, sorting

i have a list of resolutions (mobile devices, monitors etc...) and i want to sort them by resolution using bash/vim

i have (not ordered):

```
1024 x 480
96 x 120
1024 x 600
100 x 120
800 x 1280
64 x 98
640 x 320
64 x 128
640 x 960
800 x 480
80 x 120
```

then when i do:

```
cat file | sort -u
```

i get:

```
100 x 120
1024 x 480
1024 x 600
640 x 320
640 x 960
64 x 128
64 x 98
800 x 1280
800 x 480
80 x 120
96 x 120
```

why it not sorted like this and how can i do it?

```
64 x 98
64 x 128
80 x 120
96 x 120
100 x 120
640 x 320
640 x 960
800 x 1280
800 x 480
1024 x 480
1024 x 600
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use

```
sort -n -k1 -k3 file
```

This does the sort based on the numeric prefix so you'd get the list sorted by the first number

this produces

```
64 x 98
64 x 128
80 x 120
96 x 120
100 x 120
640 x 320
640 x 960
800 x 480
800 x 1280
1024 x 480
1024 x 600
```

Comment: Why `-u`? That would drop a number of the entries.

Comment: The `cat` is not necessary, simply do `sort -n -k1 -k3 file`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -n -k1 -k3  file
```

- -n is to force numeric sorting
- -k is telling it to sort using the first part then the third part of the string
- file is the name of the file. There is no reason to use `cat`. The usage is:

  sort [OPTION]... [FILE]...

[man sort](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sort/)

Comment: sorry i still see: 64 x 128, 64 x 98

Comment: @gpojd: you're misquoting how `-k` is supposed to work. Quoth the man page you linked: "start a key at POS1, end it at POS2". I think if he wants sorting on both fields, he'll need something slightly more advanced, like `awk`.

Comment: check my answer for the behavior @DanFego

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that. I don't usually sort by more than one key. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

why not use something like (the important part here are the **sort** arguments):

```
xrandr -q | grep "   " | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort --unique --field-separator "x" -h
```